# how to change image of imagebutton by checking value gets from database in for loop ? in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, imagebutton, asprepeater

I want to control the value of each row in repeater in order to change image if the value is different. My problem is that I cannot get value from repeater by trying to get of data each rows(). How can I solve it?

```
  for (int i = 0; i < repeater_talepler_list.Items.Count; i++)
        {
        ImageButton ib=(ImageButton)repeater_talepler_list.Controls[4].Controls[0].FindControl("islemeAlButton");

            bool res = CheckTalep(id, User_Name);
            if (res)
            {
                ib.ImageUrl = "~/images/confirm.png";
            }
        }
```

Comment: _"cannot get value from repeater by using rows"_ please re-read this, what does it mean? What "rows" are you referring to, what happens with your code?

Comment: `(ImageButton)repeater_talepler_list.Controls[4].Controls[0].FindControl("islemeAlButton");` this is very poor, what happens when a new control is added and your index is thrown off? Why can't you just do `repeater_talepler_list[i].FindControl("etc...")` or do you have nested repeaters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you can't find the `ImageButton` with `repeater_talepler_list.Controls[4].Controls[0].FindControl("islemeAlButton")`.

Use `FindControl` on the complete `RepeaterItem` instead of a nested control in it:

```
RepeaterItem item = repeater_talepler_list.Items[i];
ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) item.FindControl("islemeAlButton");
```